# Pinescript two alerts at the same time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

i need to start a deal and add funds at the same time in Pine Script. this because 3commas do not allow to say how high the quantity of the starting deal is. The problem is that trading view only triggers the second alert on the same closing candle, not the first one.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Test", overlay = true, pyramiding=3)

if close > open
    strategy.entry(id='Deal', comment='Start deal', direction=strategy.long, alert_message='Start deal')
    strategy.order(id='Deal', comment='Add funds', direction=strategy.long, qty=40, alert_message='Add funds')
```

i tried strategy.entry or strategy.order but this does not work either.

```
if close > open
    strategy.entry(id='Deal', comment='Start deal', direction=strategy.long, qty=20, alert_message='Start deal')

if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.order(id='Deal', comment='Add funds', direction=strategy.long, qty=40, alert_message='Add funds')
```

Is there another way to fix this? do i have to delay the second alert somehow in pine script?